# Как сделать проверку на то, что слово содержит хотя бы один символ?

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Мне надо посчитать количество слов в строке. Под словом подразумеваются слова, разделенные пробелом и не содержащие цифры и спецсимволы. В моём варианте считаются за слово пробелы, которые повторяются два и более раз подряд, а мне надо их исключить и считать только слова. Подскажите, как это сделать ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String str = "The has !been divided abs on98 the issue, with 578934 784,  
     +moderates5789 concerned @about the on: the most vulnerable.";
     System.out.println(countWords(str));
    }

public static int countWords(String input){
    //разбиваю строку на массив слов по пробелу

    int count = 0;
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    //Это я вывожу в консоль результаты, для наглядности...для себя
    //System.out.println(words.length);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));

    //считаю слова, в которых содержатся только буквы
    for (String word : words) {
        if (isValidWord(word)){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private static boolean isValidWord(String word) {
    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(c)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Используйте регулярные выражения. Это намного проще.

Comment: Я пытаюсь решить задачу теми способами, которые проходили. В цикле надо добавить условие на проверку, а я пока ни как не соображу, как его правильно написать.

Comment: @YuriiS почитайте про метод trim()

Comment: @YuriiS, не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать. У вас есть строка, в ней нужно посчитать сколько подстрок, состоящих только из букв и не содержащие пробелов? Или цифры тоже считаются "буквами"?

Comment: Под словом подразумеваются слова, разделенные пробелом и не содержащие цифры и спецсимволы. Я довольно чётко написал,  что подразумевается под словом. Вы не внимательно читали )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Делайте split не по одному пробелу а по последовательности:

   ```
   String[] words = input.split("\\s+");
   ```

   **\\s** - whitespace (пробел, табуляция, перевод строки... [Whitespace](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Whitespace_character)

   **+** - один или более
   В таком случае у вас не останется пустых строк.
2. В isValidWord замените return true на

   ```
   return word.length > 0;
   ```

   или

   ```
   return !word.isEmpty();
   ```

Каждый из пунктов по отдельности решит проблему, но я бы реализовал оба, чтобы обе части программы делали то, что от них ожидается.

В своём коде я бы реализовал функцию более лаконично:

```
private static boolean isValidWord(String word) {
    return word.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"); // если говорим о Латинице
}
```

[Whitespace](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Whitespace_character)
[Regex to match only letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters)

Comment: Если уж использовать \\s+, то слова уже будут усечены, т.е. trim() уже не нужен. И автору надо проверять не наличие пробелов, а отсутствие спец символов и цифр. Так что меняйте trim(" ") на trim("\\s+") и будет счастье!

Comment: Я написал, что каждый из пунктов в конретном куске кода сам по себе сработает. Лично я бы реализовал оба, чтобы, если, вдруг мне понадобилась функция isValidWord, то я не удивлялся, почему она не работает на пробелах. 

На счёт  trim(" "), в Java trim удаляет не пробелы а whitespace-ы.

Comment: была конкретная постановка задачи.

Comment: Отбой, trim тут не нужен, достаточно проверки length > 0. Дело даже не в том, что слова будут усечены, а в том, что в случае строки из пробелов сработает false посередине функции.

Comment: Все равно не пойму - зачем проверять на пустую строку? После split("\\s+") у нас не будет пустых строк. Не?

Comment: Вы правы, после сплит не будет строк. Поэтому я дал 2 решения, которые сами по себе работают. И от себя добавил, что я бы сделал проверку даже при 1-ом решении, несмотря на то, что это избыточно. Если мы говорим о тестовой програмке для себя, на раз и выбросить, то можно и забить. Но я привык писать код, который делает то, что от него ожидается. Поэтому либо функцию isValidWord переименовываем на containsOnlyLetters, либо считаем пустую строку - валидным словом, либо делаем проверку.

Comment: АААААА, дошло, извините! Ваше второе решение, это если не применять первое, верно? Тогда да, могут влезть пустые строки ))). Но по условиям автора валидным считается слово,  не содержащие цифры и спецсимволы. Пустая строка их не содержит )) значит тоже валидная., (да, в первом комментарии имел в виду не trim(), a split() конечно)

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код работает без ошибок. Но стоит помнить, что слова отделяются не только пробелами но и *запятыми*, *точками*, *двоеточием* и другими знаками.

Метод `split()` принимает только 1 разделитель либо регулярное выражение.

```
String[] words = input.split("\\s*[ ,.:]\\s*");
```

- `\\s*` - обозначения регулярного выражения;
- `[ ,.:]` - регулярное
  выражение, которое обозначает, любое совпадение символов в квадратных
  скобках.

Это очень простое выражение, которое подойдёт только для вашего случая. Если же в конце предложение будет стоять `!`, то последнее слово не посчитается. А если включить этот символ, то `!been` будет разбито, и `been` посчитается за слово.

Для таких случаев и существуют регулярные выражения, например, с помощью их можно считать символ `!` лишним только если он стоит после слова.